# Difference data-ng-attr-style vs ng-style

Tags: angular, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

Using `JAWS` I am not able to navigate into the tree view when I am using the attribute `data-ng-attr-style` but the navigation is working fine when `ng-style` is used.

Currently using
chrome: 111
jaws: 2023 latest

Comment: Could you please provide more code? It’s hard to tell why it’s not working if we don’t know the exact styles. I’m confused about some other things: According to the docs, Angular uses camelCase notation like `<div [ngStyle]="currentStyles">` and not dashes. Then one of your cases uses the `data-` prefix, which only is a synonym to pass validation, so the remaining question is about difference between `ng-attr-style` and `ng-style`. In this case, I guess that the latter accepts an object notation as the value, while the generic attribute directive will need a string. Which are you providing?

Comment: We also need information on how you're "navigating" with JAWS. Simple up/down arrow keys to walk the DOM? Up/down arrow keys where the event is sent to the tree itself? Tabbing? A specific key letter like `T` or `B`? (Although obviously not those two letters since they navigate to tables and buttons, respectively.) Also, what kind of tree?  [`<mat-tree>`](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview) or a third party tree such as [syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-components/angular-treeview)?